# Irreducible elements of $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{5}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is there any neat way to show that $9$ and $3-3i\sqrt{5}$ are irreducible elements of $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{5}]$, while $1+4i\sqrt{5}$ and $5-2i\sqrt{5}$ are reducible?

Comment: Hint:the field norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$9 = 3 \cdot 3$ is definitely reducible, and so is $3-3i\sqrt{5} = 3 \cdot (1-i\sqrt{5})$.

The norm of $a = 1+4i\sqrt{5}$ is $81$. There are no elements of norm $3$, so if it reducible, $a$ could only be the product of two elements of norm $9$, and these are $\pm 3, \pm 2 \pm i \sqrt{5}$. And in fact $a = (-2 + i \sqrt{5}) (2 - i \sqrt{5})$.

Finally, the norm of $b = 5-2i\sqrt{5}$ is $45$, and a similar argument leads to $b = -i \sqrt{5} \cdot (2 + i \sqrt{5})$.

So barring mistakes they all appear to be reducible, it seems.

Comment: Right, you're right... Can we use the norm to show the uniqueness of decomposition?

Comment: As you surely know, in general there's no unique decomposition in $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{5}]$. But the possibilities for the factors are just a few here, so one can check all possibilities. Sorry, it's bedtime in my time zone, I'm unable to check right now.